# Resharper Initialize field from constructor not available in 2017.1

Tags: refactoring, resharper

After I add a field I was able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose `Initialize field from constructor`. It added an argument to existing ctor or created a new ctor with that argument if it was not declared.

I wonder if this is just new version Resharper 2017.1 or old version of VS 2013? 
I have it working on VS 2015 & Resharper 2016.3. But it doesn't appear when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in VS 2013 & Resharper 2017.1.

Answer (score 2):

[ReSharper 2017.1 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/Code_Generation__Type_Constructors.html) states the following:

> ## Generating Type Constructors
>
> #### ReSharper | Edit | Generate Code | Constructor
>
> <kbd>Alt+Insert</kbd> | Constructor
> `ReSharper_GenerateConstructor`
>
> The constructor generation wizard creates a non-default constructor that takes parameters for selected fields , properties and auto-properties .
>
> All generated constructors follow the same pattern where:
>
> - Each field , property, or auto-property included in the constructor is initialized with a parameter.
> - The name of the parameter is derived from the name of the corresponding field or property .
>
> If there are non-default base type constructors, the required parameters are added to the generated constructor and passed to the base class constructor.
>
> **Tip** You can quickly generate constructors by typing `ctor` (without parameters), `ctorf` (with parameters that initialize all fields) or `ctorp` (with parameters that initialize all properties).
>
> **Tip** You can set up common code generation options on the **Code Editing | Members Generation** page of ReSharper options.

Comment: My question was not about generating a ctor. The question was about modifying an existing by adding a parameter.

Comment: I DON'T NEED GENERATE A CONSTRUCTOR I NEED TO ADD A FIELD INITIALIZATION VIA EXISTING CONSTRUCTOR OR IF NO CONSTRUCTOR CREATE A NEW ONE WITH FIELD INITIALIZATION!!! 
This was working fine in VS2015 & Resharper 2016.3. I have never used Alt + Ins | Constructor and I believe this is sort of useless feature. It is often happens that dependencies I add one by one. It is very uncommon that I need to add 2 or more dependencies at a time. Once constructor created I don't want it recreate I just want add initialization for additional new field I'm adding.

Comment: Anyone know how to enable this feature ?

Comment: I am also interested in knowing a solution to this problem. Again note, the question is not about constructor generation, but constructor field addition for existing properties.

Answer (score 1):

On my case it was not available because I disabled Build Warnings in Project Settings:

[image]

Also, suppressing warning 0169 may cause this. More info: [Resharper Support](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002952839-Initialize-field-from-constructor-doesn-t-work-in-some-project-)

Comment: Bingo!!! And I was wondering why Resharper became almost useless lately...

Answer (score 0):

I found another refactoring bulb (Quick actions menu Ctrl+.) (at least in new version of resharper for VS 2022) that have a menu "Add parameter to XXX.ctor"

[image]